# Viewing String Oscillations with a Camera

Tags: waves, string, estimation, harmonics, normal-modes

In this video, a demonstrator shows [normal modes on a string](https://The%20only%20difference%20is%20that%20guitar%20string%20is%20rigidly%20fixed%20at%20both%20ends%20while%20here%20the%20speaker%20is%20not%20at%20a%20node.).  If one is doing this with a high speed camera, how many frames per second does one need to view the oscillations?

My intuition was that you would probably need fps which is $10$ times that of the vibration frequency $f$, probably at least $6$ times.  The logic is that $2f$ is the minimum frequency to have those harmonics in the Fourier decomposition, and that one then needs at least $3$ points per half-wave, which gives $6$.  Is this type of argument roughly correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The camera has some specific sample frequency $f_s$. According to Nyquist theorem, the sampling frequency must exceed at least twice the frequency of the sampled signal.

In your case, consider that $x(t) = A \cos (2\pi f_0 t)$ is the signal with the value of the amplitude of the string. You fix some point in space and watch how changes the amplitude.

Now, you are taking samples of this signal, so it could be thought as if you had another signal which is:

$$x_a(t) = \sum_{n \in Z} x(nT_s) \delta(t-nT_s) = x(t) \cdot \sum_{n \in Z} \delta(t-nT_s)$$

where $T_s = 1/f_s$ is the sampling period of your camera. Now take the Fourier transform of the signal. By the property of the Fourier Transform of product we have that

$X_a(f) = X(f) * \frac{1}{T_s}\sum_{n \in Z} \delta(f-nf_s) =  \frac{1}{T_s}\sum_{n \in Z} X(f) * \delta(f-nf_s) = \frac{1}{T_s}\sum_{n \in Z} X(f-nf_s) $

Being $X(f)$ the spectrum of your original signal, different from zero between $[-f_0, f_0]$ then when you sample it you are convoluting with the delta function. Convoluting with delta means to shift the spectrum in the frequency axis a distance of $nf_s$. Since since every spectre is between [-f_0+nf_s, f_0+nf_s], then for not overlapping between two neighbors you need that:

$$ f_0+nf_s < -f_0 + (n+1)f_s$$
$$ f_s > 2 f_0$$

Basically, your camera's fps have to be higher than $2f_0$ but in practice you need a little more because we assumed that the filter which reconstructs the signal will be ideal (with an abrupt cutoff at $f=f_s/2$) which is impossible. Actually is easier of you oversample ($f_s$ much higher than $f_0$) the signal (if you can) because that would simplify the design for the filters with also a reduction of the quantification noise.

[image]